# removing non-increasing successive elements from list until each successive element in list is increasing

Tags: python, loops

In other words, I have a list elements (eg mass) that should increase over time. Here is an example list: starting from the last element `179.2`, each element after it should increase. We see that their are instances which this criteria is not met (after `278.8`).

```
masst = [306.4, 303.7, 301.7, 301.7, 295.7, 293.9, 288.4, 225.9, 
         225.2, 278.7, 274.6, 272.9, 269.3, 269.8, 269.1, 271.1, 
         269.7, 266.9, 266.8, 192.8, 197.6, 196.1, 254.3, 249.6, 
         244.8, 243.4, 241.2, 237.6, 234.1, 229.8, 223.2, 217.8
         211.2, 207.5, 203.5, 199.2, 195.6, 191.7, 188.0, 179.2]
```

While this is an example, I have actual data that this happens to that also vary in length. So ideally, I am trying to resolve these lists by iterating through each list until each element is increasing from its previous element.

I can rearrange the list increasing order until the actual list looks matches the rearranged list:

```
import numpy as np

check = masst == sorted(masst, reverse=True)
while(check==False):
    bool_ = [] # list of true and false statements
    for i in range(0, len(masst)-1):
        inc = masst[i] >= masst[i+1]
        bool_.append(inc)
    masst = list(np.array(masst)[bool_])
```

Doing this, it seems I am stuck in a giant loop! I'm a little confused on what I am doing wrong with my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move non-decreasing elements from a list, try this:

```
i = 1
while i < len(masst):
    if masst[i] > masst[i-1]:
        del masst[i-1]
        i = i-1 or 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

This will start at index 1, and on each iteration will check the number before the current one. If it is lower, it deletes it, and then the index of the current number will have decreased by one, so we move back (but never before index 1). Otherwise, we carry on forward. This will delete all elements of the list that are smaller than an element that comes after it.

Answer (score 1):

One problem: `while(check==False):` is always satisfied since the variable `check` isn't updated. Check just has the value `True` or `False`, and without updating it it won't change regardless of what `masst` looks like. (Looking over the code again, I don't know why you use both a `for` and a `while` loop when you only want one loop. I think you need to organize your ideas first :) .)